# Exchange Location Not Showing Up in OS X Calendar

Tags: mac-osx, exchange-2013, calendar

Exchange 2013 & Windows Server 2012 R2, OS X 10.9.5/10.10.0.

When trying to create a new meeting in OS X Calendar.app, the location field is not correctly populating with the configured meeting rooms. They all show up blank.

[image]

It is possible to add the Conference Room as an invitee to the meeting to book the room.

If you know the exact alias of the room, you can type it in the location field and it will receive the invite and book the room automatically, but then Calendar.app doesn't show the location.

(This shows accepting the room by it's exact alias)

[image]

Looking for any ideas on how to tackle this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing the AD information more closely it turns our that the "users" created by generating the resources were missing content in their "First Name" field. The display name and account name were properly completed, but not having a "First Name" made them show up blank. Adding in a name and it's fixed!!